# On the properties of prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p,q$ be two distinct prime numbers such that $p^3 \mid q+1$. 
If suppose that $p \neq 2$, then can we say anything about $p,q$?

Comment: I reckon that $q>p$.

Comment: What exactly are you after? I says that $q=p^3 t -1$ and $t$ must be even, e.g. $107=3^3 \cdot 4 - 1$ and by [DTAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) there are infinitely many such $q$, i.e. $q=p^3 (t-1) + p^3 -1$ where $\gcd(p^3, p^3 -1)=1$

Comment: ok  that right. thank you